# 3 slice expanding image with variable height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a single responsive graphic out of 3 images. A left cap, a right cap, and a middle piece that expands to fill. Seemed simple at first but has proved difficult. Here is my html.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left">
      <img src="leftcap.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="middle">
      <img src="middlepiece.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
      <img src="rightcap.png"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my css...

```
.wrapper{
   height:30%;
   width:100%;
   display:flex;
}

.middle{
   flex-grow:1;
}
```

I want the left cap to be only as wide as it needs to be based off the size of my image and the 30% height of it's parent, scaled proportionally and right aligned.

I want the right cap to be only as wide as it needs to be based off the size of my image and the 30% height of it's parent, scaled proportionally and left aligned.

Finally I want the middle image to stretch to fill any remaining width and the 30% height of it's parent.

Like i said I thought this would be simple but I haven't come up with any great ideas. I've tried flexbox, and tables. If you are looking for some context here is my example using a table. Images aren't respecting the parent heights or widths. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

http://codepen.io/asellenrick/pen/qdrrZw

Comment: css3 could draw it within a single div : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WvpZyW  . If you want to use your image , you could as well use multiple background and background-size. but it will stretch image

Answer (score 0):

```
.c img {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.c{
    width: auto;
}
.c:nth-child(2){
    width:100%;
    width: Calc(100% - 426px);
}
```

That should do it.